# Issues installing Matlab R2013a on OpenSuse 12.3 (x64)

Tags: java, linux, matlab

I am a fairly new linux user and I therefore have no idea where the error might come from. As I was trying to install Matlab (R2013a) on opensuse I had the following error:

> /tmp/mathworks_2336/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/bin/java -Xmx512m  -splash:"/home/desertfox/iso/java/splash.png" -Djava.ext.dirs=/tmp/mathworks_2336/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/ext:/tmp/mathworks_2336/java/jar:/tmp/mathworks_2336/java/jar/ja_JP/:/tmp/mathworks_2336/java/jar/zh_CN/:/tmp/mathworks_2336/java/jarext:/tmp/mathworks_2336/java/jarext/axis2/:/tmp/mathworks_2336/java/jarext/guice/:/tmp/mathworks_2336/java/jarext/webservices/ com/mathworks/professionalinstaller/Launcher -root "/home/desertfox/iso" -tmpdir "/tmp/mathworks_2336"
>
> Installing ...
>   dl failure on line 685Error: failed /tmp/mathworks_2336/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so, because /tmp/mathworks_2336/sys/java/jre/glnxa64/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so: invalid ELF header
>   Finished

I have previously mounted the .iso file and launched the following command in the mounted folder: `./install -v`, with no sucess as you can see above.

What could be the error? Java?

I have checked my java version which I believe is up to date.

```
linux-a6xj:/home/desertfox/iso # java -version

java version "1.7.0_45"

Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
```

Any Suggestion?

Thank you in advance for any help.

PS: I looked at almost all the posts and I did try the `chmod+x sys/java/jre..` as mentionned [here](http://kittipatkampa.wordpress.com/2012/02/12/matlab-on-ubuntu-from-install-make-launching-icon-to-uninstall/)

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB on Linux may still not yet be compliant with Java 7.  Uninstall JDK 7 and try again.  Install openjdk-6-jre if it still doesn't work, but it should work on its own.